# How do I configure GitHub to use SSH correctly?

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, public-key-encryption

I was following the [instructions by github](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) but got stuck on Step 2.

**Step 2:**

> If you're using macOS Sierra 10.12.2 or later, you will need to modify
>   your ~/.ssh/config file to automatically load keys into the ssh-agent
>   and store passphrases in your keychain.

I don't have a ~/.ssh/config file.

Should I Create one and put it there?

Why do they assume I have a file that I do not?

From their docs:

[image]

**Note:**

I have already generated a key pair.

Comment: Did you follow this "Generating a new SSH key" section ?

Comment: Yes.  I already did.

Comment: I think you need to create a blank config file in your home directory (under ~/.ssh/)

Comment: Nice article.  Looks like for a diiferent application but they had to create it in that case.  Seems like the GitHub directions left this part out or assumed you already did this.

Comment: And as they use the `*` it seems like their directions apply to all hosts.

Answer (score 7):

Create a blank config file under this ~/.ssh directory. (~ refers to your HOME directory)

[Reference](http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/05/setup-ssh-config-fie/)

Based on step 2 from [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent), add this to the config file,

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**Update:** 
Quoting this from [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config),

> Name
>
> ssh_config - OpenSSH SSH client configuration files
>
> Description
>
> ssh(1) obtains configuration data from the following sources in the following order:
>
> 1. command-line options
> 2. user's configuration file (`~/.ssh/config`)
> 3. system-wide configuration file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`)
>
> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used. The configuration files contain sections separated by ''Host'' specifications, and that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns given in the specification. The matched host name is the one given on the command line.

Comment: I'll mark it as the answer once you can find where the direct reference is for these configuration points.  Github does not supply it and the macosxdaily article does not supply it.    Perhaps it is in the man pages mentioned in your article?

Comment: Updated the reference